# How can I send a text output to the server monitor from an remote SSH session?

Tags: ubuntu

How can I send the text output of a shell script to the physical server screen, from an SSH session? The server is ubuntu, set as multi-user.target mode -- therefore there's nothing on the screen except for some of the boot-up messages.

This is for aesthetic purposes since my server's screen is behind my desk so I want to be able to run some fancy text from time to time when I am in a zoom session.

Thanks!

Comment: Try echo "foo" > /dev/tty (or /dev/console or /dev/tty0).

Comment: `/dev/tty` is the current terminal. `/dev/tty0` is more promising, but by default, Linux has six such virtual terminals, and in principle, you don't know which one is currently displayed.

Comment: I already tried with tty, console, tty0, even video0, video1 --- no luck :(